# Grails 3 scaffold rendering dropdown list for domains with foreigh keys

Tags: grails-3.1

If I have the following domain using Grails 3

```
class Books {

   String Title
   String Description
   Author author
}
```

The generated scaffold create a dropdown list for author, which is good however, the values on the list contains;

```
webapp.author : 1
webapp.author : 2
webapp.author : 3
```

How can I make it display a field in the author domain, like author name and last name and remove project name, domain name and the id?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to you Author Domain

```
String toString() {
    "${AuthorName}"
}
```

Change AuthorName to the actual variable you want displayed on the dropdown list.